# Why does a call to fail() compile in a Java Class using JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, junit

This seems like it shouldn't compile and run as `Object` does not have a `fail()` method. At compile time is something funky happening? (I am using NetBeans):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Test {

    @Test
    public void hello() {
        fail();

    }
}
```

Regards,

Guido

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `import static` line imports all static members of the `Assert` class into the static namespace of your compilation unit. The `fail()` call refers to `Assert.fail()`.

The confusion you are experiencing regarding where `fail()` is defined is precisely why I don't usually recommend using `import static`. In my own code, I usually import the class and use it to invoke the static methods:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Test {

    @Test
    public void hello() {
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Much more readable.

However, as [JB Nizet points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177575/why-does-a-call-to-fail-compile-in-a-java-class-using-junit#comment21379023_15177591), it is fairly common practice to use `import static` for JUnit's assertions; when you write and read enough JUnit tests, knowing where the assertion methods come from will become second nature.

Comment: What's the better way to do this? (This was the default NetBeans way to do it).

Comment: You can remove the static import, and call Assert.fail(). I agree that static imports shouldn't be abused, but statically importing Assert.* in a JUnit test is a generally accepted practice.

Comment: @JBNizet: I guess it really depends on the individual case. In this case, since most methods here begin with `assert`, the `Assert.` prefix is redundant most of the time. But if the class were designed without the method beginning with "assert" (i.e., assert methods are just `true()`, `false()`, `notNull()`, etc.), then having the class prefix makes a huge difference in readability.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks - I agree that calling the static method is far more readable.

Comment: IMO, what makes it acceptable is that a JUnit Test usually doesn't extend any class, and have methods which usually don't call each other. So any method called without any class or object prefix is "obviously" a statically imported one, from JUnit's Assert class or from Mockito or your preferred mocking framework. And not repeating `Assert` and `Mockito` everywhere makes the code easier to write and read.

Comment: The code I'm working on has a policy of no .* imports.  But you still have the option of importing ...Assert.foo;  to avoid having to spell out Assert.foo() every time.   A cross between brevity and clarity.

Answer (score 6):

This is perfectly correct and it will run and compile - I already checked using eclipse.
The reason is the static import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

that adds all the static fields or methods from the org.junit.Assert class - hence including **fail()** method.

Nevertheless a problem that might occur is the fact that the name of your test class is the same as the name of the annotation

```
@Test
```

hence it will generate an error:

> The import org.junit.Test conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Comment: +1 for pointing out the ancillary issue with the class name. Not directly relevant, but it might help someone learn something :-)

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because your classname and annotation name are same(Test).Change your class name to 'Test1' or other than Test.

Comment: The question was "Why **does** this compile", not "Why do I get this error". It was a question about mass imports.