# Importing org.junit.Test does not work however import Before and After works?

Tags: java, junit, import

When I attempt to `import org.junit.Test`, I faced a `The import org.junit.Test conflicts with a type defined in the same file` error.
I can import `Before` and `After` without any problems.
When using the `@Test` annotation, Eclipse fails to recognize it and so won't let me import it that way.

Imports:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
```

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
```

Comment: Have you defined a class named Test?

Comment: Yes, and that appears to be the problem. Frankly I am surprised it couldn't distinguish the difference through the paths

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem with your question. A tutorial wrote `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` for some reason and Eclipse gave me no suggestions. Anyone knows why they would do that? (not posting as a question, because it's not important)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you ensure that the class file name is not `Test`?
So **rename the test class to some other** name should work.
Best practice to ends the test class by "Test" word like MyServiceTest.
A similar question was posted some times back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15177609/2081121).